# null reference inside OnMouseDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing this problem: I have three Scripts. A base class (`A`), a derived class with a generic, (`A<T> : A`) and another derived class `B : A<T>`. So `B -> A<T> -> A`.

`A` has two delegates. One is called when a Coroutine finishes. The other is called when we click on the GameObject.

`A` is as follows:

```cs
public class A : MonoBehaviour {
    […]
    p ublic delegate int delegate_OnTimeElapsed();
    public delegate_OnTimeElapsed onTimeElapsed;
    public delegate void delegate_OnMouseDown(A o);
    public delegate_OnMouseDown onMouseDown;
    [...]
    public void OnMouseDown() {
        if(onMouseDown != null) onMouseDown(this);
    }
    […]
    protected IEnumerator LifeTime(){
        [...]
        if(onTimeElapsed != null) onTimeElapsed();
    }
    […]
}
```

Now I have a Prefab with a `B` Script attached that I instantiate in a Script (let's say `C`) that listens to the Return key press.

`C` is as follows:

```cs
[…]
public B prefab_Script; //Set in editor
public void Update(){
    if(Return) {
        C inst = Instantiate(prefab_Script);
        inst.onTimeElapsed += Func_A;
        inst.onMouseDown += Func_B;
    }
}

 public int Func_A(){
    Debug.Log(“Time Elapsed”);
    return 0;
}
public void Func_B(A o){
    Debug.Log(“Mouse Down”);
}
```

The thing is that inside `LifeTime` I get a correct reference to `onTimeElapsed` but inside `OnMouseDown` I see `onMouseDown` as `null`.

Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: Is it null when you do the check, or null when you attempt to invoke it?

Comment: Is `onMouseDown` already defined within the MonoBehaviour?

Comment: Maybe you should replace:
----if(onMouseDown != null) onMouseDown();------ for------- if(onMouseDown != null) onMouseDown(this);---------

Comment: **Good Lord**.  Why are you making it so complicated? It's only Unity, and only a video game.  You should be using **UnityEvent** by the way.  UnityEvent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36249404/294884

Comment: hi @ORParga.  in comments, use the single tick ("backwards tick") on your keyboard to make code fragments. just start and end the code with a single tick. `example`

Comment: You mention prefabs.  Are you aware that "links don't work" in prefabs.  you can only drag a reference "inside" a prefab. it is meaningless (if you think about it) to drag a link to something in the scene.  this is a common "gotchya" with Unity.

Comment: @ORParga yes indeed that is how the code is implemented, I forgot to write it down.

Comment: @JoeBlow I'll try `UnityEvent` this afternoon, thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33229734

I quote:

> It's allways a better way to fill all of parameters in Instantiate method e.g
>
> Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.Identity)